# 0-based index Combobox in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Combobox Form control in Excel for my drop lists. I read on the net that the combobox is 0-based index. But when I use it, I find that it is 1-based index.

When I select the first element, it shows 1 in the linked cell and not zero.

Is there an easy way to make it 0-based index ? I want to display 0 when I select the first element and select the first element when i type 0 in the linked cell.

thanks,

Comment: @JMP There is no code, it is just a general question without vba. Thats why i didnt attach any example or code. I can create an excel sheet to show what I mean but stackoverfow doesnt allow attaching files as far as I know.

Comment: When you add combo box, there is a field called (**Cell link**), you put the output cell and it will show you the index of what you selected..

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way. @aymhenry 's answer is correct. You could place the linked cell anywhere and even hide it.

Answer (score 1):

- link the combo box to set its output to cell A1 for example.
- in cell B2 type `=A1-1`